# Irritating ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null error while using view data. What is wrong with this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tried a lot of suggestions available on internet but almost all ends up with the same error. Any help would be appreciated, thank you. I am new and learning, please excuse if this elementary level question. Why I am not able to access `ViewData` in my view?

Controller

```
public ActionResult BroadcastData()
{
    List<Broadcast> BroadcastList = new List<Broadcast>();
    BroadcastList = (from d in _db.Boradcast
                    select d).ToList();            

    ViewData["BroadcastData"] = BroadcastList;

    return View(BroadcastList);
}
```

View

```
@model List<SideCar.Models.Broadcast>

@{
    var viewDataMyObj = ViewData["BroadcastData"] as List<SideCar.Models.Broadcast>;
}

@foreach (var item in viewDataMyObj.ToList())
{
    <h2>@item.BroadcastHeading</h2>
}
```

Following error occurs:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
> System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument
> argument)

If I remove `.ToList()` from view after `viewDataMyObj.ToList()` within `@foreach` then I receive following:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the **BroadcastList** doesn't have any data. Put a break point on the last line of your method and check that list.